# Perl HTTP::Request Put -> Method not allowed

Tags: perl, rest, http

i'm using Perl to access a Rest-Api:

```
use LWP::UserAgent;
use HTTP::Request::Common;
my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new;

my $req = HTTP::Request::Common::PUT("http://xxx:yyy/...");
$req->header('content-type' => 'application/json');
$req->authorization_basic('abc','xyz');

my $put_data = '{
        "description" : "TestPut"   
    }';
$req->content($put_data);

my $resp = $ua->request($req);
if ($resp->is_success){
    print $resp->content() . "\n";
}
else{
    print "PUT failed:\n";
    print $resp->message . "\n";
}
```

But i am getting a "Method not allowed" Message.
The GET works fine.
Could this be a Problem by the Http-Server (Tomcat) or a firewall?

$req->as_string:

```
PUT #URL 
Authorization: Basic xxx= 
Content-Type: application/json 

{ 
           "description" : "TestPut"
           }
```

Comment: Can you show what `$req->as_string` looks like?

Comment: Also there is a typo in your code. You have `HTTP:Request...` with one `:` instead of two `::` in line 5. Please fix that. Is this your actual code?

Comment: And please always `use strict` and `use warnings`.

Comment: Please [edit] that into your question and delete the comment. Also remember the auth-string is not encrypted, just encoded as base64, so you might want to use fake credentials. ;)

Comment: thanks for that ;) i edited it above

Comment: Now only the line breaks are missing. Those are important for HTTP communication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The GET works fine. Could this be a Problem by the Http-Server (Tomcat) or a firewall?

Yes, you have to look there. GET and POST are the usual methods to access a web site while PUT is usually used for REST or WebDAV and not used by the web browser (unless you do your own XHR requests). Thus it might be that a firewall or HTTP server restricts access to this method.